# macOS High Sierra Freeze on every Screen Lock

Tags: macos, high-sierra, crash, reboot

Since the High Sierra update my Mac is freezing and restarts automatically whenever I lock the screen.

After reboot I get a bug report popup which details the error:

```
Anonymous UUID:       1E525FB8-9AFA-9D2F-850B-DC173D1FA627

Tue Jan 16 13:49:34 2018

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f8b49c58b): "UPSB: thunderbolt power on failed 0xffffffff\n"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IOPCIFamily/IOPCIFamily-320.30.2/IOPCIBridge.cpp:1296
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff91fa37ba90 : 0xffffff800ac505f6 
0xffffff91fa37bae0 : 0xffffff800ad7d604 
0xffffff91fa37bb20 : 0xffffff800ad6f0f9 
0xffffff91fa37bba0 : 0xffffff800ac02120 
0xffffff91fa37bbc0 : 0xffffff800ac5002c 
0xffffff91fa37bcf0 : 0xffffff800ac4fdac 
0xffffff91fa37bd50 : 0xffffff7f8b49c58b 
0xffffff91fa37bdb0 : 0xffffff7f8b49d0ca 
0xffffff91fa37bdd0 : 0xffffff7f8b49b42f 
0xffffff91fa37be20 : 0xffffff7f8b4a5cc9 
0xffffff91fa37be40 : 0xffffff800b276d85 
0xffffff91fa37beb0 : 0xffffff800b276b2a 
0xffffff91fa37bed0 : 0xffffff800ac89e74 
0xffffff91fa37bf40 : 0xffffff800ac89965 
0xffffff91fa37bfa0 : 0xffffff800ac014f7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[C08F7FC1-78A4-3A1B-BFE2-C07080CF2048]@0xffffff7f8b494000->0xffffff7f8b4c8fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
17C88

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.3.0: Thu Nov  9 18:09:22 PST 2017; root:xnu-4570.31.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 87641697-A3DD-30C4-B010-E65ECE57550B
Kernel slide:     0x000000000a800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800aa00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800a900000
System model name: MacBookPro13,1 (Mac-473D31EABEB93F9B)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 4378444473626
last loaded kext at 247860950295: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f8bca0000, size 69632)
last unloaded kext at 313979484202: com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1 (addr 0xffffff7f8ba53000, size 8192)
loaded kexts:
org.pqrs.driver.Karabiner.VirtualHIDDevice.v041100  4.11.0
com.asix.driver.ax88179-178a    1.8.0
ryangoulden.driver.IOUSBHIDDriverDescriptorOverride 1
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.2
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.24
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   280.12
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.16.21
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.16.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.10.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.2f2
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.3
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPCHPMC   2.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   6.01.2
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    211
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSKLGraphics  10.3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSKLGraphicsFramebuffer   10.3.0
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.31.8
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.30.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 127
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1220.28.1a3
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   183
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.IOBufferCopyEngineTest    1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 280.12
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    526
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.16.21
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUARTTransport  6.0.2f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.2f2
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTv1   3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTCommon   3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 280.12
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 280.12
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.16.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   517.22
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.16.21
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    376.6
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    517.22
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   209.2.2
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  311.9
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    1204.13
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   203
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 127
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.2f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.2f2
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  1204.13
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    1201.8
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    52
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2CController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  52
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.6.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 3.0.60
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBufferCopyEngineFamily    1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.30.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.30.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140.30.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    650.5
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCRTC    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
Model: MacBookPro13,1, BootROM MBP131.0212.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.4 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.36f97
Graphics: Intel Iris Graphics 540, Intel Iris Graphics 540, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x802C, 0x4D5435324C31473332443450472D31303720
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x802C, 0x4D5435324C31473332443450472D31303720
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x159), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.37.5.1a3)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.2f2, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AX88179 USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet, Ethernet, en4
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: USB 2.0 HUB

USB Device: Jabra PRO 9470
USB Device: USB KeyBoard
USB Device: USB Mouse
USB Device: USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
USB Device: USB 3.0 HUB

USB Device: AX88179
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.2
```

Can you guys make anything out of this error report?

Answer (score 1):

First suspects in any kernel panic are the 3rd party kexts

```
org.pqrs.driver.Karabiner.VirtualHIDDevice.v041100  4.11.0
com.asix.driver.ax88179-178a    1.8.0
ryangoulden.driver.IOUSBHIDDriverDescriptorOverride 1
```

I only recognise the first of those, but you should try a combination of...

1. Safe mode
2. a new account
3. uninstall the related apps

& see which stops the panics.

Comment: In addition to Tetsujin's advice, as a test I would also disconnect all those devices from the USB ports except for the keyboard and mouse, restart and see if the problem recurs. If not, add a device at a time, restart, and test. Perhaps you'll find a particular device and its kexts will be to blame.